# jquery asmx and web.config

Tags: jquery, asmx

Please help!
We use jquery to call a remote asmx in .net.

we only want logged-in users to hit this service.
we put it under a protected location (web.config), it works fine but when the session expires we get the login html page back.
I've read some other articles from people with the same problem.

my question is, if we moved the asmx out to an unprotected folder and added the following condition
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) to catch if the user is not logged-in would that be the same?

I hope I explained my question properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the web service (.asmx) to an unprotected folder **or** add explicit access to the service in your `web.config` (within `<configuration>` section)

```
<location path="[filename].asmx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>    
</location>
```

Then, as you had already thought, do a check in the webservice to verify authentication and have your response indicate to the page a need to re-login.

Comment: Hi mdmullinax, thanks for your quick reply, just out of curiosity why do I need to add explicit access to the service? does it make any difference?

Comment: when declaring `<allow users="*" />` you're giving `all users` (anonymous and authenticated) access to the file  otherwise the file is only allowing authenticated users to access that file.

Comment: oh yes I read your email again and I noticed you put "or" I thought you meant move it to an unprotected folder but grant explicit access which I considered redundant. Thanks